# Match name that starts between two characters entered by the user

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I need to write a query that matches based on the user entering two letters and then matching any name in the customer table that starts with any letter between the two an put them into a cursor. I have tried to use `REGEXP_LIKE` but can not get the pattern to match and I am running out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all start with an uppercase then simply use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER("name"),1,1) BETWEEN 'C' AND 'G'
```

Table

```
name
Alan
Ben
Chris
Dave
Eddy
Fred
Gregg
Henry
```

Output

```
name
Chris
Dave
Eddy
Fred
Gregg
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7cf66/6/0

Comment: Names with `G` not in the results list. Use this: `between 'C' and chr(ascii('G') + 1)`. Also, there could be problems with non ascii characters.

Comment: @Dmitry I Agree, I could do with some sample data/more info to give a more comprehensive answer

Comment: names will always be uppercase, no non ascii characters and i could add the UPPER() just to be sure correct?

Comment: yeh having `WHERE UPPER("name") BETWEEN 'C' AND 'G'` would work

Comment: That worked thank you very much! I didn't realize that BETWEEN would check the first letter

Comment: Adding a substr around the upper("name") to select the first letter would ensure that all names beginning with a G are selected, fwiw

Comment: Let me update the answer with the suggestions in the comments

Comment: @Austin bear in mind that if you have an index on the name column, it won't be used - instead, you'll have to create a function-based index to match the predicate in your query, i.e. `SUBSTR(UPPER("name"),1,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the REGEXP_LIKE solution you were originally looking for. Match case-insensitive starting with c-g inclusive.

```
select name
from table1
where regexp_like(name, '^[C-G].*', 'i');
```